# How to insert a record in Sqlite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios4

please anybody tell me how to insert records in sqlite through objective c?

Comment: I assume you've read the SQLite documentation, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a block of code like this

```
-(NSString*) GetDatabasePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
        NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your Database"] ;
}

-(void)InsertPurchase {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;
        NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath];
        NSString *query;

        if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&db) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Your insert query"];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)
                        == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

This can be your interface

```
@interface Database : NSObject {
    sqlite3 *db;
}
```

Comment: Use the `101 010` button to indent a block of text, marking it as code.  Also, it's better to convert tabs to spaces before copying and pasting.

Comment: Hi Mike can you elaborate your point.Btw thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The code you pasted in had a bunch of tabs in it, so (on my browser, at least) the indentation in the input text and the output code isn't the same.  Additionally, the tab key doesn't work in most web page text areas (it navigates to the next field instead).  So try using a "Convert Tabs to Spaces" command in your text editor before copying and pasting into StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks but i have already added the database file in my project,so should I use this method:--(NSString*) GetDatabasePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
        NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your Database"] ;
}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (and honestly if you don't you're crazy), then it's really simple:

```
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/path/to/my/database.db"];
if ([db open]) {
  [db executeUpdate:@"insert into myTable (col1, col2) values (?, ?)", @"foo", [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]];
  [db close];
}
```