# Downloading and saving images in iOS

Tags: iphone, image, save, download

I am creating an iPhone app and in that I want to download multiple image files from web service. And I want to save the images in the local folder in the app itself and save the path to each files in SQLite database. How can I implement this? Please help.

Comment: add your some code here.

Comment: Questions containing solely "GIMME TEH CODEZ" are not considered good.

Comment: It is a question like saying "Please create application for me with App Icon as well.."

Comment: i just asked how can I implement this, not for some codes. And if someone is ready to help, I expected some ideas only. I have got some links already but confused little bit, thats why I asked. And people are more interested to downvote than helping someone. Great..!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
**// Get an image from the URL below**
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yorimageurl"]]];

    NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

    **// Let's save the file into Document folder.**

    NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pngPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",Dir];// this path if you want save reference path in sqlite 
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"saving jpeg");
    NSString *jpegPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpeg",Dir];// this path if you want save reference path in sqlite 
    NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
    [data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"saving image done");

    [image release];
```

**>> Update Additional:**

You need to save image name(unique name that you can do early..right..!!) in sqlite database and you can make path or retrieve image using that name as i shown below.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];// here you jus need to pass image name that you entered when you stored it.
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how can i get the path to each files? so that I can access/retreive the images.

Comment: you need to save `pngPath` in database. This is where the image is being saved. You can access it later. Or you can just store our file name in database and create a String variable for `NSString *Dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];` and append it while accessing the file

Comment: Happy for you...enjoy. Than after i like to suggest you to save yourself from negative voting ask some different question or add some code that you tried so far.I added +1 for up your moral...enjoy

Answer (score 2):

After implementing @Nit's code.. you can refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310852/how-to-insert-a-record-in-sqlite) for insert record in database.

This is showing how to insert record in DB. and for getting path read my comments in @Nit's answer.

**UPDATE:**

For getting path of each downloaded file you have to keep unique name for each file. Now you will have the path where you are writing file that is unique path for every file. Now you simply need to execute insert query every time you download a file or need to save filepath in array and execute query later according to your requirement. Don't forget to give different file name to every file otherwise only single file will be there and your path will be same.

For getting unique filename you can use timestamp:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf.png", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

**UPDATE2:**

You have path now like: `/Users/John/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/84A837AA-7881-4D99-B6E2-623DC9A2E5D3/Documents/test.png`

For getting Image in Image view:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourPath];
//[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourPath]];
UIImageView *imgView = // Alloc + Init + Setting frame etc
imgView.image = img;
```

This will show image in your imageview

Hope this helps

Comment: its navigating to this same page?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i know how to insert the code in to DB, i had issue only with getting the path for each downloaded files.

Comment: see my updated answer. If you still have doubt please explain it what exactly it is.. as path is there so you can get it.

Comment: now its all clear except one part, I have got the path to the image like "/Users/John/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/84A837AA-7881-4D99-B6E2-623DC9A2E5D3/Documents/test.png" how can I show this image in a imageview?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10970/discussion-between-kapil-choubisa-and-john)